# Gradient and intersection point

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying multivariable calculus at the moment. I recently worked with a problem where one had to find the vector that describes the tangential direction $\vec{v}$ for a specific point of intersection $\vec{a}$ between two scalar valued functions, let's call them $f$ and $g$ respectively.

What I used in order to solve the problem was to evaluate the following: $\vec{v}=(\nabla f \times \nabla g)(\vec{a})$.

I'd pretty new to the concept of gradients as well. But I do understand that the gradient is a normal vector to the level surface for a specific point in space. However, I don't really understand why the tangential vector has to be normal to both functions at  the point of intersection. I assume this might be a question involving linear algebra more than multivariable calculus itself. Still, I don't just want to take this idea for granted, and I really want to understand as to why this is the case.

I'd be glad for any ideas that can help me deepen my understanding of this.

Comment: I think you should deepen your understanding of `cross-product` in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Tanamas Be careful with your terminology. It doesn't make sense to talk about "the intersection of two functions"; I suspect what you're asking about is the intersection of the **level surfaces** of two functions. Similarly, it doesn't make sense to say that the tangential vector is "normal to both functions"; I'm actually not sure what you have in mind here.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for your comment. Why is there a distinction between intersection of two functions and level surfaces, if I may ask? In my eyes, when I think of intersection of two functions, I see that as an intersection in the R^2 plane, but maybe that's not the way I should be viewing it.

Comment: A function is not a graph. For example, the function $f(x) = x^2$ is not the same thing as the graph $y = x^2$, the function $f$ is a rule that takes an input $x$ to its output $x^2$. Note that the function $g(x,y) = x^2 - y$ is also not the same thing as the level curve $g(x,y) = 0$. Notice that $y = f(x)$ and $g(x,y) = 0$ are equations using these functions that describe same curve, but neither of these functions **is** the curve.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $\nabla f(\vec a)$ and $\nabla g(\vec a)$ are the normal vectors to the level sets of the functions $f$ and $g$ that pass through $\vec a$.

In order for a vector to be parallel to the level set of $f$, it needs to be orthogonal to $\nabla f$. Similarly, a vector is parallel to the level set of $g$ when it is orthogonal to $\nabla g$. A vector that is parallel to the intersection of these level sets is parallel to both of these surfaces, and is therefore orthogonal to $\nabla f$ *and* orthogonal to $\nabla g$, which is why it is parallel to the cross product $\nabla f \times \nabla g$.